# How to sum up all rows of many dataframes

Tags: r

I want to sum up all rows from many dataframes.
My dataframes are named SP1, SP2, ... , SP48

I tried it with:

```
for (i in 1:48) {
 nrow(paste0("SP", i)) 
}
```

But as it seems, paste0 gives back a charachter, so nrow cant calculate anything.

Thank you

Comment: [Put them in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames).

Comment: `df_list = mget(ls(pattern = "SP[0-9]+"))` then `sum(sapply(df_list, nrow))`

Comment: worked perfectly
could u explain how the pattern coding worked?

Comment: It's a regex pattern `"SP"` matches literally "SP", and then `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more digits. So it looks for all objects in your R environment that are named "SP" followed by numbers. Since you know your names and they are simple, you could have `paste`d them together directly, `df_list = mget(paste0("SP", 1:48))`. Using a regex pattern gives more flexibility (which isn't really necessary here).